# Upload a file to SFTP server

Tags: vbscript, sftp

I had to upload a file from local folder to an SFTP server using VBScript.
I have searched for this and found several websites discussing on this matter.
All are discussing about using third party tools.

How can I upload a file to an SFTP server with out using a third party tool like `WinSCP.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need either an external program (like [`psftp.exe`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)) or a [COM object](http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/objects/sftp/), none of which are included with the operating system.